# How to fix the menu selection for quiting

Tags: python

So i want this to run when number 7 is entered it should quit the current program. I have tried with the rest of my menu selection but I just want to fix the quit at the moment.

```
if menu_selection == "7":
    quit()
```

Comment: Your question needs more context.

Comment: Please select one of the following options:

1. Sell a Game
2. Profits on Sales
3. Restock Games
4. Amount Of Games in Stock
5. Price of Games
6. Total Games Sold
7. Exit The Application
so when i enter 7 i want it to quit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are guessing `quit()` is the way to exit. 
You should try `sys.exit()`:

```
 import sys  # at the head of your program

 ...
 your program
 ...
 if menu_selection == "7":
     sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit your program you can use `exit()` from `sys`

```
import sys
[...]
if menu_selection == "7":
    sys.exit()
```